# RayCaster in three js use with point cloud

Tags: three.js

i have a big point cloud in scene with over than 90k points .
i am creating a measure functionality. so on click i am getting the mouse coordinate in 2d view and using raycaster to see this position intersection with camera , when i log the intersection it is giving a huge number of points like 22k 44k ... how can i be very specific with raycaster and select an exact point.

Note: i used threshold and it didn't help at all.

thank you in advance!

const rayCaster = new THREE.RayCaster()
const mouse = new THREE.vector2()

mouse.x = ....
mouse.y = ....  (the basic calculation to get mouse coords ..)

rayCaster.setFromCamera(mouse, this.camera)

const intersections = raycaster.intersectObjects(this.scene.children)

and i also tried to intersect only the point cloud .... it didn't help as well

Comment: It's not mentioned in the docs somehow, but, when you raycast against points, objects of intersection will containd the field `index`, which is the index of intersected point. Thus, `intersections[0].index` will give you the index of the vertex (closest by distance), whose coords you'll obtain from `position` attribute.

Comment: but intersections[0] will not be accurate to get its index it is always giving the closest point to the camera , and sorry didnt mention that the point cloud is a depth point cloud and not just flat point cloud